# Can't type accented characters in Google Chrome on Mac

Tags: macos, google-chrome

I am unable to type any accented characters in Chrome using the <kbd>Opt</kbd>. This used to work but recently stopped, on the same computer. I can use other special characters such as <kbd>Opt</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> for a ü or <kbd>Opt</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> for a ñ, but the accent option does not work (nothing is typed). I can use <kbd>Opt</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> in other apps such as Stickies or Safari fine.

There are posted questions about this that said the problem was a Chrome extension. However, I also experience this problem in private browser mode with all extensions disabled. I practice Spanish on various sites and not being able to type accents is annoying.

Comment: What language keyboard layout are you using?

Comment: Disabling all chrome extensions fixed for me the issue where I couldn't type Opt+o to get "ó". Thanks

Answer (score 1):

### You may try like this to get accented characters

<kbd>Opt</kbd> + <kbd>u</kbd> then press <kbd>u</kbd> you will get **ü**

<kbd>Opt</kbd> + <kbd>e</kbd> then press <kbd>e</kbd> you will get **é**

<kbd>Opt</kbd> + <kbd>n</kbd> then press <kbd>n</kbd> you will get **ñ**

Comment: The OP clearly states in the question that opt+u and opt+n is already working for him and that opt+e isn't working. Can you edit this to address that concern?